# Getting the c3p0 "ClassNotFound" Exception on MCServer start

Tags: java, plugins, classnotfoundexception, c3p0, bukkit

iam trying to use MySQL Connection Pooling using c3p0.

I want to use c3p0 for a bukkit plugin.

The MANIFEST.MF looks as follow and is placed at Pooling.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> class-path: ./Pooling/lib/c3p0.jar ./Pooling/lib/mchange.jar

I've placed the 2 files at

> plugins/Pooling/lib/

However, it keeps printing this error:

> 2013-09-13 16:35:19 [SEVERE] Error occurred while enabling Pooling
>   v1.0.0 (Is it up to date?) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource     at
>   com.frostforce.Pooling.Database.setup(Database.java:11)   at
>   com.frostforce.Pooling.Main.onEnable(Main.java:16)    at
>   org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:217)     at
>   org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:457)
>     at
>   org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:381)
>     at
>   org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:282)
>     at
>   org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:264)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:313)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.f(MinecraftServer.java:290)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:250)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:151)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:391)
>     at
>   net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:582)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:80)
>     at
>   org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:53)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 13 more

I have no idea at all what Iam doing wrong at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `jar` ran from the `plugins` folder?

Comment: Yes. All mysql commands are getting executed from the plugin folder

Comment: I run it with oracle and my jar files are under lib, this is what my class-path looks like     Class-Path: lib/ojdbc6.jar lib/properties lib/c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar lib/c3p
 0-oracle-thin-extras-0.9.2.1.jar lib/mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar, can you try to give Pooling/lib instead of ./Pooling. It is obviously not finding the jar files right now.

Comment: Tried it without the "./" at the start and got the same error :/

Comment: _All mysql commands are getting executed from the plugin folder_ It has nothing to do with mysql. Where are you running your application from?

Comment: The application is included at the starting process of my bukkit server. It's a plugin [Server/plugins/Pooling.jar] and is actually trying to set up the database at startup

Comment: where are the other jar files located? Is your code able to read any other jar file which are located at some other location ?

Comment: The 2 libs are located at Server/plugins/Pooling/lib/<files here>. Yes they are